# Display invalid value for Date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a custom date validator that looks like this:

```
# app/validators/date_validator.rb
class DateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  DATE_REGEX = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    before_type_cast = "#{attribute}_before_type_cast"

    raw_value = record.send(before_type_cast) if record.respond_to?(before_type_cast.to_sym)
    raw_value ||= value

    return if raw_value.blank?

    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must be in correct date format")  if (raw_value =~ DATE_REGEX).nil?
  end
end
```

In my model, I use that validator with the following code:

```
validates :date_assigned  :date => true
```

My problem is, that when a user enters an invalid date, I'd like to display the invalid date on the form so they can correct it. But currently, when I enter "11111" into the date assigned field on the form, I believe the rails typecasting is converting it to nil (date_assigned is a date value in the DB), so instead of "11111" being displayed, nothing is.

If a user enters "01/01/01" (invalid per the date regex), the view is displaying "0001-01-01" instead of the original (invalid) string of "01/01/01".

Can someone help me figure out how to do this? Thanks